# Mobile Website essentials..?

Tags: php, jquery, android

I have decided i'll have to make a mobile version of my website. so ive tried reading about and come here to confirm and get your approval.

1) I have decided im going to use jquery mobile framework to create it. what are its limitations? according to me...none. educate me.

2) I don't have a smartphone or similar? how will i test the website during development? i have read about phone emulators... what is the best phone emulator you wud recommend that emulates a vast array of phones?

3)Once ive developed the website... i'll need a smart way of phone detection... so as it redirects to mobile website... i know there are libraries for this... again i need a recommendation here

Please help me answer these questions or direct me towards the right path... i know a lot of mobile website noobs need these questions answered.

btw, my website is veepiz.com. incase that can help

Comment: jquery mobile is good but its is still beta (or alpha?) anyway things like the animation of the slider are laggy (on an iphone 4 and htc legend).

Answer (score 1):

1.) I would stay away from using javascript for a mobile website unless you know that the device(s) you will be targeting support javascript. Most modern smart phones support javascript but you might run into issues with older devices.

2.) I can't speak on emulators but there are a few firefox plugins that allow you to modify the headers to allow you to simulate what your site would look like on a particular mobile device.

3.) You can use an open source tool like [Wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net) for device detection. It comes in several flavors including php.

As with any kind of development, it's about analyzing what your target devices/audience will be and gearing your site development towards those devices while gracefully degrading features for those devices that are't supported.

Comment: Just read this... so it has graceful degradation for non-javascript browsers... " jQuery Mobile supports both high-end and less capable devices, such as those without JavaScript support. Progressive Enhancement consists of the following core principles (source: Wikipedia):"

Answer (score 1):

Some points I know are these

Try not to use flash in your mobile website. [Apple has no intention](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) on supporting flash on their phones.

jQuery Mobile is still inn alpha, but have heard good things so far. Check out [jQuery Mobile's graded browser support](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) for the support they provide to different browsers.

Comment: Can youtube videos be viewed on mobile phones? the only videos on mysite are from youtube.. :-)